# Error with the command System.IO.File.WriteAllLines()

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, io

Hello i am trying to save an object that i have been created and its returning to me error: "represents as a series of Unicode character" on this line: `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\MYDATA\hi.txt", somOne);`

here is the code:

main class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Persone somOne = new Persone("bob", 5, 200);
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\MYDATA");
            // the Error line Is HERE \/
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\MYDATA\hi.txt", somOne);
        }
    }
}
```

persone class:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Persone
    {
        private String name;
        private int id;
        private int age;
        public Persone(String name, int id, int age)
        {
            setName(name);
            setId(id);
            setAge(age);

        }
        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public void setId(int id)
        {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }
        public void setAge(int age)
        {
            this.age = age;
        }
        public int getAge()
        {
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

do i need to chang the type of "somOne"? and how?

Comment: I don't recognize that error. Can you copy/paste the exact error message please?

Comment: The verbatim error message is pretty important here. Can you reproduce it here, word for word?

Comment: The phrase "Represents text as a series of Unicode characters." is the XML documentation summary of the [String class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.String);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0.3);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true).  That has nothing to do with  the error, you just hovered over the String type in your code file.

Comment: @user2970504 - I'm pretty sure the answers below are correct, but for future reference you need to copy the *whole* error message. What you have now is still missing the crucial parts

Comment: ok: class System.String Represents text as a series of Unicode characters. Error: The Best overloaded method match for 'Syste.IO.Fill.WriteLines(String, System.collections.generic.irnumerable<string>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user2970504 - Much better. Thank you.

Comment: If i want to open it back in the next run how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines expects array of strings (or IEnumerable<string>) as second parameter, so code you have should not even compile. You can add to your Person class something like:

```
public string[] ToStringArray()
 {
     //And put it everything you need to store
     return new[] {name, id.ToString(), age.ToString()};
 }
```

and call like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\MYDATA\hi.txt", somOne.ToStringArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just save an object like that. They don't automatically format themselves for save to disk.

You want to look into either [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9.aspx) or override the `.ToString()` method for the class and use `File.WriteAllText()` instead.

Comment: `WriteAllLines` is expecting an array.  Serialization is not required here.

Answer (score 0):

According to MSDN, `File.WriteAllLines` requires an `IEnumerable<string>` or a `string[]` as input (the full signature is `File.WriteAllLines(string, IEnumerable<string>)` or `File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])` where the first string is the path and the second is the set of lines you wish to write.

Passing your `Persone` object is not the same.  At the very least you would need to override .ToString() on your object, better might be to write a new method `.WritePersone()` or something like that.

With the first, you'd call WriteAllLines like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\MYDATA\hi.txt",
                             new string[] {somOne.ToString()});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm getting your question correctly.
By this

```
        // the Error line Is HERE \/
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\MYDATA\hi.txt", somOne);
```

you are saying you're getting an error on the above line?

You should've got a compile time error there.  The 2nd parameter of WriteAllLines takes either an array or IEnumerable of strings.

Try adding this to your Persone class

```
public string[] Dump()
{
    string[] tmp = new string[3];
    tmp[0] = id.ToString();
    tmp[1] = name;
    tmp[2] = age.ToString();
    return tmp;
}
```

then write to file using

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\AppData\Roaming\MYDATA\hi.txt", someone.Dump());
```